# Perl output overwrites itself

Tags: perl, io, newline, printf

I have code which loops through lines in a file, and tries to print out each line with something added at the start and end.

However, I get output like this: "nominalte cows".

Basically, the bit after the line (nominal) overwrites the start of it. I know that removing the chomp and regex lines stops this effect, but I need it to be on one line without spaces. Where am I going wrong?

```
while ($line = <INPUT>) {

        chomp $line;
        $line =~ s/ //g; 
        printf "\@attribute %s nominal\n", $line;
}
```

Comment: What are the elements of `@attribute`?

Comment: Sorry, missed the escape char, it was meant to be plaintext (\@att...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your input file is probably from MS Windows with end of line encoded as CR-LF. You can also just `s/\r//` to remove the CR.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what was going wrong, I'll remember that in future :) (I used $line =~ s/\r//g; in my solution). Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

You might have `\r` in your variable.  Try using `\s`:

```
$line =~ s/\s//g;
```

See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for the meaning of `\s`.

Comment: I think SO answers should be self-contained.  Why not simply explain the meaning of `\s` along with the link for more info?

Comment: why would your strip out all whitespace to get rid of `\r` (carriage returns)? `$Line =~ s/\r//g`; That said, choroba's answer is probably the root cause anyway (same solution)

Comment: Great! That's exactly what was going wrong, I'll remember that in future :) (I used $line =~ s/\r//g; in my solution). Cheers!